# javascript array from existing divs innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

Let's say i create dynamically some divs, each has it's dynamically created id (div0, div1, div2, etc.) and i'd like with a function to pass through currently existent divs and put their innerHTML into an array (one, two, three in this case), how can i achieve this in javascript?

html example:

```
<div contenteditable="false" id="div0">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <span id="one-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div1">
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <span id="two-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div2">
  <a href="#">three</a>
  <span id="three-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('div')` (Or your custom selector, like `$('#divcontainer > div')`) should already be an array. You can use `.map()` to get the html into an array: `$('#divcontainer > div').map(el => $(el).html())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use spread syntax

```js
const divsContents = [...document.querySelectorAll("div>a")].map(e=>e.innerHTML);
console.log(divsContents);
```

```html
<div contenteditable="false" id="div0">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <span id="one-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div1">
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <span id="two-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div2">
  <a href="#">three</a>
  <span id="three-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add `>a` in the query selector is perfect

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my doubt here is does it mess if i have others "a" inside divs around the page that i don't want in the array? I'd like it to get the innerHTML only of divs with id starting with "div" for instance, or of divs inside a parent div with id="maindiv" let's say, is it enough to do like $('#maindiv').querySelectorAll(etc..) ?

Comment: depending on your selector (`document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='div']")`) for divs with id starting with "div" for example

Comment: Thanks, this last solution returns me the html for the <a ..>...</a> too, around the desired text to parse, i made it like: ("div[id^='div'] >a") and works

Answer (score 2):

Using some magic from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array), because `document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList and not an array, we can get the div elements into an array and use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the div content into an array.

```js
var divs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'));

console.log(divs.map(div => div.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div contenteditable="false" id="div0">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <span id="one-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div1">
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <span id="two-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div2">
  <a href="#">three</a>
  <span id="three-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Ideally you should be using a selector like `#divcontainer > div` to fetch all the divs in the container, but if you know all the ID's, you can use a selector such as:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#div0, #div1, #div2')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery or javascript function for get your `div`:

```
myArray[0] = document.getElementByID("div0").innerHtml;
myArray[1] = document.getElementByID("div1").innerHtml;
myArray[2] = document.getElementByID("div2").innerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give same class to divs and access by $('.class-name') or add a container div and get your div array by $('#divId div').

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop after creating a `divs` collection using `querySelectorAll`:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let arr = [];


for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  arr.push(divs[i].innerHTML);
}

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div>hi</div>
<div>hi2</div>
<div>hi3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
var arr = [];
function myFunction() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
   arr.push(anchors[i].text);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So many ways of doing this. Yet an other way: using ES6 `Array.from`

```js
let divsA = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='div'] a"));
divsA.map(a => console.log(a.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div contenteditable="false" id="div0">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <span id="one-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div1">
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <span id="two-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" id="div2">
  <a href="#">three</a>
  <span id="three-close">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
  </span>
</div>
```